# How to solve error unprotecting the session cookie

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am getting the following warnings, AFAIK this is related to cookies and GDPR, please CMIIW..

how to solve this? need help..
thanks a lot in advance

Regards
Don

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
        }); services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        ...
        ... 
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseCookiePolicy();
```

> [WRN] Error unprotecting the session cookie.
>       System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: The key {833d40c6-95a9-4d70-9f1c-b5024726a65c} was not found in the key ring.
>          at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingBasedDataProtector.UnprotectCore(Byte[] protectedData, Boolean allowOperationsOnRevokedKeys, UnprotectStatus& status)
>          at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingBasedDataProtector.DangerousUnprotect(Byte[] protectedData, Boolean ignoreRevocationErrors, Boolean& requiresMigration, Boolean& wasRevoked)
>          at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingBasedDataProtector.Unprotect(Byte[] protectedData)
>          at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session.CookieProtection.Unprotect(IDataProtector protector, String protectedText, ILogger logger)

Comment: There's something wrong with the data protection setup, which you've neglected to include in your question. Are you specifying a custom keystore location?

Comment: Alternatively, you may be accessing a cookie set by another site on the same domain, without specifying a shared keystore.

Comment: sorry, I don't understand what do you mean?, I did not use Cryptography in cookies, but I used it in other class for some purposes.. the key was stated in the class

Comment: The cookies ASP.NET Core sets (auth/session) are always encrypted.

Answer (score 2):

unprotecting the session cookie

I had the same issue,
thing is your site cookie is old and do not match with the current site, its key is different,

happens only due to the new source release and the user being with old source cookies.

Try removing cookie first and then try, it will disappear